# Why the output shape is not conform

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

When implementing this model :

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=1,strides=1, padding="causal",activation="relu"), 
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True), 
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
model.compile(
    loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(), 
    metrics=[
        metrics.MeanSquaredError(name='my_mse'), 
        metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(name='my_rmse'), 
        metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(name='my_mae')
    ]
)
```

The input is a set of np array of 3 values, but the output has the same shape than the input. Even if the label is a simple float. Why is that ?
Thank you

Comment: @perpetualstudent No, why? This seems to be a regression problem, please do not give incorrect and unneeded advice.

Comment: oops sorry i thought it's classification problem, sorry